# Are WHERE clauses pushed down into VIEWS with QUALIFY clauses?

Tags: databricks, parquet, databricks-sql

If the definition of a VIEW has a QUALIFY clause, when selecting from the view, are WHERE clauses pushed down, or is the entire view SQL evaluated before applying the WHERE clause?

e.g.,

```
CREATE VIEW vw_some_table (
  table_id,
  fk_id,
  type_cd,
  insert_dt
)
AS SELECT
  table_id,
  fk_id,
  type_cd
FROM some_table
QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_id ORDER BY insert_dt DESC) == 1
```

with SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_some_table
WHERE type_cd = 'TYPE1'
```